# ANDROID GPS / Invalid Listener

Tags: android, gps

I'm trying to write from scratch a GPS tracker, but it fails just at the beginning.

For some reason the following code gives me a IllegalArgumentException : invalid listener: null.

```
mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
mLocationManager.getProvider(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 1, mLocationListener);

mLocationListener = new LocationListener() {
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            Log.i(TAG,"There is some noticeable movement");
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            // Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            // Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            // Auto-generated method stub
        }
}
```

Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

Its because on this line

```
mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 1, mLocationListener);
```

The `mLocationListener` is `null`. Initialize it before requestLocationUpdates`.

```
mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
mLocationManager.getProvider(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

mLocationListener = new LocationListener() {
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            Log.i(TAG,"There is some noticeable movement");
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            // Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            // Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            // Auto-generated method stub
        }
}
mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 1, mLocationListener);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the code,

```
mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
mLocationManager.getProvider(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);


mLocationListener = new LocationListener() {
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            Log.i(TAG,"There is some noticeable movement");
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            // Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            // Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            // Auto-generated method stub
        }
}

mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 1, mLocationListener);
```